# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError (Ruby Rake test)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rake-test

This is making me crazy, i dont know whats the problem here

Im doing rake test test/model/user.rb but i dont get whats the problem.

```
UserTest#test_test1:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: Error: error de sintaxis en o cerca de <<)>>
Line 1: INSERT INTO "megusta" () VALUES ()

INSERT INTO "megusta" () Values ()

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips


require 'test_helper'
```

The test case

```
require 'test_helper'
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test "test1" do

  fixtures :users

  new_user = User.new :provider => (:one).provider

  assert new_user.save

  end
end
```

and the logs

```
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:27.572[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36m (522.6ms)[0m  [1mDROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "facebook"[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.984[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (10436.8ms)[0m  CREATE DATABASE "facebook" ENCODING = 'utf8' (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.500[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36mSQL (3.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "plpgsql"[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.167[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (111.4ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "albums" ("id" serial primary key, "nombre" character varying(255), "fecha" date, "descripcion" character varying(255), "lugar" character varying(255), "imagen" character varying(255), "privacidad" character varying(255), "fk_usuario" integer, "activo" character varying(255), "playalbum" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp) (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.288[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36m (119.2ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "amigos" ("id" serial primary key, "fk_usuario1" integer, "fk_usuario2" integer, "status" character varying(255), "fecha" date, "leido" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp) [0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.422[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (132.6ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "comentarios" ("id" serial primary key, "coment" character varying(255), "nivel" integer, "notificacion" character varying(255), "fk_album" integer, "fk_usuario" integer, "fk_comentario" integer, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp) (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.479[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36m (54.3ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "megusta" ("id" serial primary key, "tipo" character varying(255), "fk_usuario" integer, "fk_comentario" integer, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp) [0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.577[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (96.2ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "multimedia" ("id" serial primary key, "nombre" character varying(255), "fecha" date, "descripcion" character varying(255), "lugar" character varying(255), "api" character varying(255), "tipo" character varying(255), "fk_album" integer, "activo" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp) (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.699[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36m (119.7ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "provider" character varying(255), "uid" character varying(255), "name" character varying(255), "first_name" character varying(255), "last_name" character varying(255), "location" character varying(255), "description" character varying(255), "image" character varying(255), "phone" character varying(255), "email" character varying(255), "privacity" character varying(255), "favorite" character varying(255), "oauth_token" character varying(255), "oauth_expires_at" timestamp) [0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.706[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (2.2ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying(255) NOT NULL) (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.766[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36m (57.2ms)[0m  [1mCREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.767[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT version FROM "schema_migrations" (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.769[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36m (1.9ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131018031139')[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.772[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (2.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131016224150') (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.772[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131018031015')[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.773[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131018031051') (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.775[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36m (1.4ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131018031105')[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.775[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131018031120') (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.806[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.957[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations" (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.969[0m [[33mhmm[0m] Unable to load megustum, underlying cause No such file to load -- megustum 

 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:773:in `try_to_load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:792:in `block in require_fixture_classes'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:790:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:790:in `require_fixture_classes'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:768:in `fixtures'
C:/Users/Deniel/Documents/GitHub/mediabox/test/test_helper.rb:12:in `<class:TestCase>'
C:/Users/Deniel/Documents/GitHub/mediabox/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/Users/Deniel/Documents/GitHub/mediabox/test/helpers/buscaramigo_helper_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:73:in `block (3 levels) in define'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:73:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:73:in `block (2 levels) in define'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:72:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:72:in `block in define'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:61:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>' (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:38.975[0m [[33mhmm[0m] Unable to load multimedium, underlying cause No such file to load -- multimedium 

 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:773:in `try_to_load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:792:in `block in require_fixture_classes'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:790:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:790:in `require_fixture_classes'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:768:in `fixtures'
C:/Users/Deniel/Documents/GitHub/mediabox/test/test_helper.rb:12:in `<class:TestCase>'
C:/Users/Deniel/Documents/GitHub/mediabox/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/Users/Deniel/Documents/GitHub/mediabox/test/helpers/buscaramigo_helper_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:73:in `block (3 levels) in define'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:73:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:73:in `block (2 levels) in define'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:72:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:72:in `block in define'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:61:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>' (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.846[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36m (1.6ms)[0m  [1mALTER TABLE "albums" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "amigos" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "comentarios" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "megusta" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "multimedia" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "users" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.906[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  BEGIN (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.956[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36mFixture Delete (0.0ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM "albums"[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.105[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35mFixture Insert (4.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "albums" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2014-01-19 05:28:39', '2014-01-19 05:28:39', 980190962) (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.106[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36mFixture Insert (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "albums" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2014-01-19 05:28:39', '2014-01-19 05:28:39', 298486374)[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.112[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35mFixture Delete (0.0ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "amigos" (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.115[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36mFixture Insert (2.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "amigos" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2014-01-19 05:28:39', '2014-01-19 05:28:39', 980190962)[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.115[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35mFixture Insert (0.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "amigos" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2014-01-19 05:28:39', '2014-01-19 05:28:39', 298486374) (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.119[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36mFixture Delete (0.0ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM "comentarios"[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.122[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35mFixture Insert (2.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "comentarios" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2014-01-19 05:28:39', '2014-01-19 05:28:39', 980190962) (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.123[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36mFixture Insert (0.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "comentarios" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2014-01-19 05:28:39', '2014-01-19 05:28:39', 298486374)[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.124[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35mFixture Delete (1.0ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "megusta" (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.126[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36mFixture Insert (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "megusta" () VALUES ()[0m (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.126[0m [[31mwtf[0m] PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «)»
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "megusta" () VALUES ()
                               ^
: INSERT INTO "megusta" () VALUES () (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.127[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  ROLLBACK (pid:6544)
[0;37m2014-01-19 00:58:39.128[0m [[0;37mmeh[0m] [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mALTER TABLE "albums" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "amigos" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "comentarios" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "megusta" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "multimedia" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "users" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL[0m (pid:6544)
```

Any idea? Do I need to create test data for each table in fixtures?

Comment: I dont know... Thats my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your test/fixtures folder, maybe you have a empty megusta.yml file.

Comment: You were right. Some test/fixtures/.yml file need some data to run the test. Thanks!